# What port does DynamoDB use

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What port do communications to AWS DynamoDB use? Is it HTTPS on port 443?

The only references I can find are to do with the stand-alone DynamoDB that AWS provides (not the cloud version) which looks like it is HTTP over port 8000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All AWS APIs use the standard HTTPS port 443.

Comment: To extend on this... Amazon DynamoDB is not like traditional SQL databases where a user logs-in to a particular port to run commands. Instead, DynamoDB is accessed via API calls, which include authentication information. The API calls are web-based and (preferably) secured with SSL, so communication would be on port 443.